# How to keep all bootstrap columns in the same row with meta tag viewport in mobile view?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I'm working on a to-do list web application, I have an input field and a submit button in the same row in two columns.
I have added the meta tag viewport to make it mobile friendly but it renders each of them in a row.
I want to make the input field and the submit button on the same row in mobile view so what do i need to do?

I have tried to wrap with the form-inline class but still breaks into two rows in mobile view

Here's the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and here's the my input and submit button tags:

```html
<div class="row" id="myForm">
    <div class=" col-sm-11">
            <input class="form-control" id ="toDoListInput" placeholder="What needs to be done?" formControlName="toDoListInput" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" >
            <input class="btn btn-light" type="submit" name="Add" onclick="appendToList()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the col-xs ? I think col-sm is for smaller-ish tablet size range

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work with all mobile sizes,
Also on the ones that fit, i have to horizontally scroll.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? The column naming convention for mobile-size is different if you're using 3.x vs. 4.x.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written right now the columns will each automatically collapse to the equivalent of `col-xs-12`, because your highest specified media breakpoint for anything else is `col-sm-*`.

You had mentioned the `col-xs-*` breakpoint not suiting every potential mobile size, resulting in horizontal scrolling. One way to avoid that potential hiccup is to reconsider how you are displaying your `<input>` and button elements. Bootstrap has a great UI component for this: `.input-group`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="myForm">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="toDoListInput" placeholder="What needs to be done?" formControlName="toDoListInput" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-light" role="button" type="submit" onclick="appendToList()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The combination of `.input-group` with `.input-group-btn` causes your form input and button to align together, and the `.form-control` class will scale down (or up) as needed depending on the width of the viewport.